# How to Dim the Entire Screen and Place a Button in the Center

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a trial application in Windows Phone 8, and I would like to allow the user to choose whether to purchase the app or not on a button click event. My idea was that after so many launches, the MainPage would have some sort of dimming or overlay on top of it so the user may not interact with the app, and a message and button would appear on top, ultimately asking the user if they want to purchase the app or not. Is it possible to do something like this? I am not sure if actually creating a brand new page would be better, but my thought is that if the user can see the functionality behind the dimmed overlay, they would be more enticed to go ahead and make a purchase to get back to those features. How might I do something like this?

EDIT

Maybe adapt something like this http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Create_simple_overlay_with_UserControl_in_Windows_Phone ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward -- start by adding an overlay like a border and the "purchase" button, hidden by default.  Just make sure that the overlay is the last child of the root, so that it will always appear on top:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <!-- Main content here -->

    <Border x:Name="overlay" RowSpan="10" ColumnSpan="10" 
        Opacity="0.5" Background="#666"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Button x:Name="btnPurchase" 
        Content="Purchase"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding StartPurchaseCommand}"
        Visibility="Collapsed"  />
</Grid>
```

Now add a "purchase" visual state to show the overlay+button:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PurchaseStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="TrialState" />
            <VisualState x:Name="PurchaseRequired">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="overlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame> 
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="btnPurchase" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame> 
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Then it's just a matter of calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "PurchaseRequired", true)` on startup, whenever the trial period has elapsed.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "PurchaseRequired", true);` in my `OnNavigatedTo` event just to see what would happen, but I am getting an 'InvalidOperationException'. I plan on saying something like after 15 days has passed present the overlay. What would you recommend for this?

Comment: @Matthew I'm not sure what the deal is -- that should work if the states are defined under the root element of your page.  Maybe it would be easier to set the visibility by binding to a VM property.

Comment: Hm I'm not sure. What about the use of the `Popup` control in Windows Phone 8? Is there a way to show a popup and dim the rest of the screen and block the UI from any user interaction?